# how to read googlesheet data in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, google-sheets

New to reactjs and  I have to build a react component that display information from a google sheet in a scrollable ticker widget

I found an NPM package to enable the scrolling widget https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-ticker

In addition , I see the google-sheet package but this run on the  server. https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet

can you please give some hints on how to read and display the content of a googlesheet data using reactjs

Comment: Hi, is the spreadsheet publicly accessible, or is it only shared with certain accounts?

Comment: it is currently shared with a few users

Comment: Consider using Sheets API. Take a look at this [JavaScript quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) if you want to authorize the request client-side. If you want to do that server-side, there are quickstarts for many languages. Here's a guide for [reading data from a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading). Consider providing more details about your situation, if you need further clarification about this.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api).

Take a look at this [JavaScript quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js) if you want to authorize the request client-side.

If you want to do that server-side, there are quickstarts for many languages.

Here's a guide for [reading data from a spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values#reading).